# Basis for Null Space at a Point

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I have a [plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(geometry)#Point%E2%80%93normal_form_and_general_form_of_the_equation_of_a_plane) at a point $\boldsymbol{r}_{0}\in\mathbb{R}^3$ with normal vector $\boldsymbol{n}\in\mathbb{R}^3$.
$$
\boldsymbol{n}^\top (\boldsymbol{r} - \boldsymbol{r}_0) = 0
$$
My aim is to find a basis for this plane. I know that if this plane was through $\boldsymbol{r}_0 = \boldsymbol{0}$ then one way in which I could find a basis for the plane would be via SVD decomposition. The last $2$ columns of $U$ would form a basis for $N((\boldsymbol{n}^\top)^\top) = N(\boldsymbol{n})$, the null space of the "matrix" $\boldsymbol{n}$.

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
    n_1 & n_2 &  n_3
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    r_1 \\
    r_2 \\
    r_3
\end{pmatrix} = 0
$$

My question is:

> How can I find a basis for the plane at $\boldsymbol{r_0}$ with normal vector $\boldsymbol{n}$ using SVD/QR decompositions? I DO NOT want a different method, I just want to adjust this method to find the correct basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the plane at the origin, with basis $\{u_1, u_2\}$ and at some other point $r_0$. These are *parallel*. So $\{u_1, u_2\}$ serves as a basis for the second one as well.

Well...to be more honest, the second one isn't a linear subspace of $3$-space (it doesn't contain the zero-vector), so it doesn't even have a (linear) basis. But it has an *affine* basis, or "coordinate system", with origin $r_0$ and the two vectors from the origin-plane as vectors. Or it has an affine "frame", consisting of $r_0, r_0 + u_1, r_0 + u_2$.

Or if you want to consider it as lying in the tangent-space to $\Bbb R^3$ at $r_0$, it *is* a subspace of that, with basis $(r_0; u_1), (r_0; u_2)$, where I'm using the standard identification of $T\Bbb R^3$ with $\Bbb R^3 \times \Bbb R^3$ here.

Comment: The reason why I am asking is because I am trying to plot these vectors. If I just solve $n^\top r = 0$ then I get parallel basis vectors, as you say. However, I want to plot them AT the point. (Essentially, I have a sphere, and I want to plot the basis of the tangent of the sphere at a point)

Comment: How would I then practically find those basis but at the point?

Comment: I think I need to know your precise definition of "vector". (Be warned: I'm not lying when I tell you I know at least 5 different (albeit equivalent) ones!) But if I wanted to "draw them at that point" (in software, whatever), I'd draw an arrow from $r_0$ to $r_0 + u_1$, and another from $r_0 $ to $r_0 + u_2$.